# write a block in cache that it's dirty bit was set

Tags: caching, cpu, cpu-architecture

In computer architecture , if processor want to read a block in cache which it's dirty bit was set , then the processor will re-write this block to the memory or just read the block without write allocate ?

Answer (score 0):

For reads, the data is read from the cache, as that is the latest updated data. For writes to the same block, the new data (to the same address) is updated and the dirty bit is set again. Only when there's a conflict miss (due to two different addresses sharing the same cache block) would the data actually be pushed to the next level of memory hierarchy.